# Hardware Accelerated H264 Decode using DirectX11 in Unity Plugin for UWP

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, uwp, directx-11, hololens

I've built an Unity plugin for my UWP app which converts raw h264 packets to RGB data and renders it to a texture. I've used FFMPEG to do this and it works fine.

```
int framefinished = avcodec_send_packet(m_pCodecCtx, &packet);
framefinished = avcodec_receive_frame(m_pCodecCtx, m_pFrame);
// YUV to RGB conversion and render to texture after this
```

Now, I'm trying to shift to hardware based decoding using DirectX11 DXVA2.0.

Using this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/supporting-direct3d-11-video-decoding-in-media-foundation

I was able to create a decoder(ID3D11VideoDecoder) but I don't know how to supply it the raw H264 packets and get the YUV or NV12 data as output. 
(Or if its possible to render the output directly to the texture since I can get the ID3D11Texture2D pointer)

so my question is, How do you send the raw h264 packets to this decoder and get the output from it?

Also, this is for real time operation so I'm trying to achieve minimal latency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @youaresoomean hey, can you take a look at this please..

Comment: Since you already have it done using FFMPEG, I'd like to suggest to you to use FFMPEG's dx11 hardware decoding directly (check this FFMPEG example): https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c

Comment: @VuVirt Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to get it to work using that example. I'll be running some benchmark tests to check the performance boost.

Comment: @VuVirt It is an alternative solution, so sure! :)

Comment: @rohitn did you run your benchmark tests? Could you share some of the findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have it done using FFMPEG, I'd like to suggest to you to use FFMPEG's dx11 hardware decoding directly.

Check the HW decode FFMPEG example for details: [github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.‌​c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c)